# DataTables rows seems empty list C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datatable

I try to fill ListView with custom DataTable. I want to create columns and rows dynamically, from strings (toParse contains rows, toParse2 contains column names). It doesnt seems to work. When I start the program I see smthing like this (System.Data.DataRowView):
[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj5uq.png)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ListView items;
        string toParse = "1 12 13\n2 15 16\n3 9 14\n20 123 541235\n4 1234 567";
        string toParse2 = "id value1 value2";
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            items = GenerateListView(10,10);
        }
        public ListView GenerateListView(int posx, int posy)
        {
            ListView listview = new ListView();
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            string[] columnNames = toParse2.Split(' ');
            foreach (string name in columnNames) table.Columns.Add(name);

            string[] lines = toParse.Split('\n');
            foreach(string line in lines) {
                string[] values = line.Split(' ');

                if (values.Length==columnNames.Length)
                {
                    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                    table.Rows.Add(row);

                    for (int i=0; i<values.Length; i++)
                    {
                        row[i] = values[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            listview.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;

            this.grid1.Children.Add(listview);
            return listview;
        }
    }
```

In addition, when I debug table it seems that Count of Rows actually works, but the List is null(?).

Comment: Can you please share xaml of your view?

Comment: <Grid Name="grid1"></Grid>
I said I want it to generate dynamically in c# declaration rather than in xaml.

Comment: `ListView` does not have any automatic mechanism for generating column layout based on `DataTable`. You could generate columns manually or use `DataGrid`, which can auto generate columns.

Comment: @SolisQQ, I've added an answer for this. Please check it and let me know if it's working fine for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your listview columns. You can use GridView to define your columns of ListView.

I've added `GridView myGridView = new GridView();` and define its columns using data binding.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ListView items;
        private string toParse = "1 12 13\n2 15 16\n3 9 14\n20 123 541235\n4 1234 567";
        private string toParse2 = "id value1 value2";

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            items = GenerateListView(10, 10);
        }

        public ListView GenerateListView(int posx, int posy)
        {
            ListView listview = new ListView();
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            GridView myGridView = new GridView();

            string[] columnNames = toParse2.Split(' ');
            foreach (string name in columnNames)
            {
                table.Columns.Add(name);

                GridViewColumn gvc = new GridViewColumn();
                gvc.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(name);
                gvc.Header = name;
                gvc.Width = 100;

                myGridView.Columns.Add(gvc);
            }
            string[] lines = toParse.Split('\n');
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] values = line.Split(' ');

                if (values.Length == columnNames.Length)
                {
                    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                    table.Rows.Add(row);

                    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                    {
                        row[i] = values[i];
                    }
                }
            }

            listview.View = myGridView;
            listview.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;

            this.grid1.Children.Add(listview);
            return listview;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh thank you, it works perfect :). I almost abandon this idea and got back to the listBox with string format.

Comment: I'm happy to help... :)